# How to break a content in verbatim to make it appear in a justified manner?

Tags: verbatim, justification

Unable to get a nice appearing justified output using verbatim. The long lines are not getting broken.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{verbatim}
        The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks. The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks. The following is printed verbatim, but with line breaks.
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: justification and line breaks don't go with verbatim.  What are you trying to have happen?  Are you just wanting a different font?

Comment: Yes a similar one to verbatim appearance.

Comment: Then do you just need a different font family?  See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles#Reference_guide

Comment: Verbatim outputs the text as you have given it; it will neither add nor delete lines. Just use a different font rather than verbatim text.

Comment: If it's just about the font, not about the other special properties, you could use `\texttt{<your text>}` instead. If it's also about the special input properties of displaying everything as input, there are packages that allow line breaks in such environments, for instance `listings`, but also others.